# multiprocessing Issues: Different behaviours on different systems, ranging from correct to absolutely incorrect

Tags: python, hardware, multiprocessor

I am processing large text files for data(>40MB) and doing it serially was taking a lot of time.  I decided to use the python 3.5 multiprocessor package.  When it works, it is significantly faster but I am getting mixed results.

I am running the following code on two systems, the first a very spec'd out dual xeon server, the second my X1 Carbon thinkpad.  Both are running ubuntu16.04 and plain python 3.5.

```
queue = Queue()
cpus = cpu_count()

def get_gauging_data_from_files(self,fileName,id):
    global cpus
    print("I:", id)
    data_lines = getFileData(fileName)
    pool = Pool(cpus)
    block = getBlock(data_lines)
    for i in range(len(data_lines)):
        if data_lines[i].startswith("Axial Slice at"):
            block.append([data_lines[i:(i+54)]])
            i += 53
    print("Line index got to:",i, "CpuCount:",cpus, "block size:", len(block))
    pool.map(getBlockData,block)
    block_data = []
    i=0
    while not queue.empty():
        block_data.append(queue.get())
        i+=1
    print("Queue Count:",i)
    raw_data = np.asarray(block_data,dtype=np.float64)
    raw_data = raw_data[raw_data[:,0].argsort()]
    data_axial = raw_data[:,0]
    data_radial = raw_data[:,1:361]
    print("data_axial size:", len(data_axial)," data_radial size:", len(data_radial))
    print("O:", id)
    return data_axial, data_radial
```

The dual Xeon gives the following output.

```
I: True
Line index got to: 450586 CpuCount: 24 block size: 16686
Queue Count: 16686
data_axial size: 16686  data_radial size: 16686
O: True
```

The block size of 16686 matches the queue count of 166886 which indicates each argument to the worker function has been processed and a corresponding data point added to the queue.

The laptop, running on the exact same file/data, the program quickly terminates giving the following out put:

```
I: True
Line index got to: 450586 CpuCount: 24 block size: 16686
Queue Count: 525
data_axial size: 525  data_radial size: 525
O: True
```

This indicates that for some reason the 16686 arguments being passed to getBLockData are not nearly all being processed.

I would expect the laptop to run significantly slower than the Xeon, but I would also expect it have processed all the data passed into the pool.  I am mystified...can anyone shed the light of experience onto this particular issue?

The worker function looks like this:

```
def getBlockData(B):
i=0
#print(len(B[0]))
queue_item = [[B[0][i].rstrip().split()[3]],
    B[0][i+4].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+5].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+6].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+7].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+8].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+9].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+10].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+11].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+12].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+13].rstrip().split()[1:10],

    B[0][i+17].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+18].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+19].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+20].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+21].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+22].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+23].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+24].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+25].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+26].rstrip().split()[1:10],

    B[0][i+30].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+31].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+32].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+33].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+34].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+35].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+36].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+37].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+38].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+39].rstrip().split()[1:10],

    B[0][i+43].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+44].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+45].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+46].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+47].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+48].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+49].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+50].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+51].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+52].rstrip().split()[1:10] 
]
queue_item = [val for sublist in queue_item for val in sublist]
queue.put( queue_item )
```

Comment: We cannot see what `getBlockData` does, you don't `join()` or `close()` the pool and does anything run on Windows?

Comment: Ok... the edit came as I commented. Something in `getBlockData` looks badly designed for efficiency.

Comment: I would agree, I don't think that's the issue though.  The code works correctly on the xeon and then not at all on the laptop... my understanding is that this should not be the case.

Comment: I would take any suggestion you have for doing getBlockData more cleanly though... its a bit of a hack.

Comment: I don't join or close because my understanding of using a pool with map is that it basically takes care of all that for you.

Comment: Day by day I find horrible differences between Windows and other OS. You didn't address that question. But I made some other observations too.

Comment: Um ok, I'm not so sure it does both the `join` _and_ `close` but I could well be wrong on that, I would need to read up

Comment: from the documentation pool.map blocks until all tasks submitted are complete - which is essentially a close/join pair as I understand it... I did try close/join but they seem to only like processes not pools.

Answer (score 0):

The following code seemed to work for me, cruising though the posts online I found that what I was missing was the fact that pool.map wants to return values.   I also added the pool.terminate() because to clean up the python processes after the code terminates.

Both the laptop and the xeon run this happily... still not sure what was going on previously...

```
def getBlockData(B):
    i=0
    queue_item = [[B[0][i].rstrip().split()[3]],
    B[0][i+4].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+5].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+6].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+7].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+8].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+9].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+10].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+11].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+12].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+13].rstrip().split()[1:10],

    B[0][i+17].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+18].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+19].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+20].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+21].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+22].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+23].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+24].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+25].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+26].rstrip().split()[1:10],

    B[0][i+30].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+31].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+32].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+33].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+34].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+35].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+36].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+37].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+38].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+39].rstrip().split()[1:10],

    B[0][i+43].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+44].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+45].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+46].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+47].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+48].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+49].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+50].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+51].rstrip().split()[1:10],
    B[0][i+52].rstrip().split()[1:10] 
    ]
    queue_item = [val for sublist in queue_item for val in sublist]
    return queue_item

def get_gauging_data_from_files(self,fileName):
    data_lines = getFileData(fileName)
    pool = Pool()
    block = getBlock(data_lines)
    block_data = []
    for i in range(len(data_lines)):
        if data_lines[i].startswith("Axial Slice at"):
            block.append([data_lines[i:(i+54)]])
            i += 53
    print("Line index got to:",i, "block size:", len(block))            
    block_data.append(pool.map(getBlockData,block))
    pool.terminate()
    raw_data = np.asarray(block_data[0], dtype=np.float64)
    raw_data = raw_data[raw_data[:,0].argsort()]
    data_axial = raw_data[:,0]
    data_radial = raw_data[:,1:361]
    print("data_axial size:", len(data_axial)," data_radial size:", len(data_radial))
    return data_axial, data_radial
```